# AWS EC2をDBサーバーにして、MS ACCESSをODBCで接続する方法

Tags: amazon-ec2, ms-access, odbc

MS ACCESSをフロントエンドにして、AWS EC2（MYSQL）へODBC接続することは可能でしょうか？ どなたか方法をご存知でしたらご教示ください。

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるのでは？ [MySQL Connector/ODBC 8.0のインストール方法](https://a1-style.net/mysql/mysql-connector-odbc-80-install/), [AWS EC2上のデータベースに外部からODBC経由で接続するための設定](https://a1-style.net/amazon-web-service/ec2-mysql-redmine-odbc/)

Comment: Kunifさん　ありがとうございます。　ODBC接続することができました。